# wcf service getting called twice

Tags: jquery, html, css, wcf, knockout.js

I am using infinite scrolling on my html table. Here is code i use to do infinite scrolling

```
$('#divTable').bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            currentPageNo = currentPageNo + 1;
            myservice(id, pageSize, currentPageNo);


        }
    });
```

When page loads it fills my table with 100 records because i pass pagesize as 100. When i scroll down at bottom of table it calls this code `myservice(id, pageSize, currentPageNo);` twice. I dont understand why its calling twice.

Here is my html

```
<div id="divTable" style="height: 535px;overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: hidden">
                    <table>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: myData">

                            <tr >

                                <td style="padding: 8px;width: 50px;" data-bind="text: Id "></td>
```

```
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to hijack the scroll event and use it to allow my user to advance one page at a time. On a track pad you can have what I call "intertial scrolling" which will cause your event handler to fire too many times.

You need to be able to identify inertial scrolling and only run your event handler if the scrolling is not inertial scrolling.

Here is a code snippet:

```
var event = normalizeEvent(event);
  if(event.timeStamp - smartScroll.timeStamp < 50){

    smartScroll.inertia = true;
  }else{

    smartScroll.inertia = false;
  }
```

Based on the value for smartScroll.inertia, you would determine if the event handler should react or not.

You can pick out the full code here, although there is a lot here that does not pertain to your case: 
http://www.oliverpetkovski.com/javascript/main.js

Comment: What is smartscroll? Is it possible to modify my code and show me how to do?

Comment: I can try to get you going in the right direction. Can you create a code pen and send me a link to it?

Comment: I would be extremely thankful to you if you can provide me link with code.

Comment: If you can just create a code pen here, then I will work on it: http://codepen.io/. Just put your html and javascript in there and send me a link to your pen

Comment: Can i post fiddle instead?

Comment: Please answer me if possible

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete answer using my "smart scroll" code and jquery draggable to allow you to call up records via scrollbar and mousewheeel.

https://github.com/maggiesavovska/knockoutEndlessScroll

NOTE: if you still see the "intertial scroll" happening, you have to adjust the if statement on line 99 increasing the threshold between the actual event timestamp vs. the timestamp of the last scroll event. This is what will indicate if the scroll is real and intended by the user or inertial. If the figure is too high, your user will get stuck when trying to scroll really fast one after another. If it's too low, then the endless scroll will advance unexpectedly. Here is the code I'm referring to:

```
if(event.timeStamp - smartScroll.timeStamp < 70)
```

You also have to make sure to set up the array as observable in knockout and set the values for it on each scroll event using the proper set method as defined by knockout.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

To see what I'm talking about, refer to line 15 in the view model and line 55 of my smartScroll.scrollEvent

For the data I've created a data object in the js file which can later be deleted once you integrate your service. To use your service, search the code for the comment '//call service', this is where you will need to call your service, passing in the pageNumber variable which already exists in the code, a page size, and return the array.

You also need to know the full length of the array containing your data. This will determine the size of the draggable scroll element and it will all you to position the scroll element at top or bottom if you are at the end of the data. Anywhere in the code where it says model1.newArray.length, you would have to supply the length of your entire array of data.

Search for comments '//start delete later' and delete everything from there to '//end delete later' once you've integrated your service.

keep in mind that model1.curArray has to be set using a setter and not using an equals sign. This is how it is currently so make sure not to change that. This is what I mean: 
CORRECT (USING SETTER): model1.curArray(model1.newArray[model1.pageNumber]);
INCORRECT (USING EQUALS SIGN): model1.curArray = model1.newArray[model1.pageNumber];

Some of the code can be optimized. If I ever get around to it, I will clean it up, but it works.

Comment: can you delete your other answer? Also i still dont understand where exactly in code i should call my service

Comment: It looks like your code works only for mouse scroll. I want for both mousescroll and manually dragging of scrollbar. Also i get error "Object doesn't support property or method 'preventDefault'" on this line e.preventDefault(e)  Also your code runs whenever i scroll on other div's in my page. I want this code to run only for particular div

Comment: This can be done best with jquery ui draggable. I will work on an example.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Just added another edit, so make sure to pull down the latest changes from github

Comment: you have not added any height to div called "divTable"

Comment: Referring to your code i have call service twice . on line 27 and 60. Also this line 108 var event = normalizeEvent(event); gives error about duplicate declaration and its quite natural. Also you are asking me to call service on line 165 and 180. I have to call it so many times. I need to declare 2 arrays curArray and newArray? currently i have only one observable array binded to my table which is called myData. So now i need 1 more?

Comment: You don't have to have more than one array, that was only for me because I was using some test data. You can delete the code between //start delete later and //end delete later. In terms of calling the service multiple times, aren't you fetching data anyway each time you scroll? I'm sure it could be consolidated into one method, but I don't have time fore that now.